# Safe way to claim hard fork coin

Tags: blockchain-fork, airdrop

let said ALice own 10 BTC at address "ABC", at block height 3,456,700, it was hard-forked to Bitcoin "Zaza".

At block height 3,500,000. The stable version of Bitcoin"Zaza" wallet is available.
Thus, at block 3,456,710, Alice uses her old bitcoin wallet software and transfer out all her coins into another address "XYZ".

Then, at block height 3,500,000, she uses Bitcoin "Zaza" wallet to claim her Bitcoin Zaza.
Is this method safe?

Comment: I wish I knew this earlier so that I could maximize my profit with no security risk.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Zaza and BTC in one wallet it's suggested that you first send your BTCs away (because they're more precious and the BTC client is more trustworthy) then your Zazas so that the Zaza client can't steal your BTC.

Comment: yupe! I just want to find out whether i miss out on something with my procedure.